# How to get smooth transitions between colors while keeping sharp edges?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, blur, paint.net

I am trying to smooth out images of colored wave forms while trying to keep sharp edges.

Example of a source image:

[image]

I've had some limited success using surface blur, while the transitions between each color is smoother I am loosing sharpness on edges:

[image]

Is there a technique, filter of effect I could employ to get such result ?

**EDIT**

here's the result thanks to @boblet

[image]

**EDIT 2**

I've found a pseudo-alternative that somewhat achieves the same goal though it's not as pretty.

[image]

The thing is to draw gradient lines with the middle color (0.5) being a little darker.

Actually this is the poor man's alternative until I can get hold of the surface blur algorithm which doesn't seem as easy to implement as it sounds.

Comment: What software are you working with?

Comment: I did that with Paint.net but I can use Photoshop and Gimp as well.

Comment: So what you want are a blur between the colours "inside" the shape, but keep the sharp edge with the white background?

Comment: Yes exactly that.

Comment: I don't know where you get the source images from but if you have a way to produce a waveform with the color distribution you want but without any white area left (maxed out everywhere), you could blur that and put the white from the image you have now as a layer on top. That way you wouldn't dilute any colors with white as you do now.

Comment: Actually I do produce the waveform so I'll be able to do that, thanks for the tip !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Paint.net and Gimp

Below is a detailed example of how to do this in Photoshop. However, both Gimp and paint.net have the same capabilities, though the tools have slightly different names.

The Gimp equivalent to Photoshops `magic wand tool` is `Fuzzy select.` You should be able to achieve the same result.

### photoshop.

Select the white background with the `magic wand tool`
You do this by first clicking on the top part of the white, hold shift and then select the bottom part.
[image]

Right click, and choose `select inverse` from the menu.

[image]

Choose the blur tool,

[image]

and blur your colours into each other to your hearts content.
[image]

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: @Takkat maybe you could make that an answer, for future reference?

Comment: Paint.Net also works the same way

Comment: Heheh, paint too. Nice. Good to know; I will see if I can incorporate this in some way.